# Updating Ubuntu 14.04 Failing

Tags: updates

I am very new to Ubuntu, and am having trouble running an update in order to install the ubuntu-desktop gui.  This is a vm server in a production environment, and my end goal is to update my ssl cert on this server.

When i run apt update, I receive the error message :

W: Failed to fetch http://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/8.2/ubuntu_14.04/packages  HttpError404

E: Some index files failed to download.  They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I have tried to research this, but I cannot find an answer.  I believe it has something to do with updating the sources.list file as the error message looks like the download location for the owncloud update has changed.  I have no idea what the new location might be, or how to update the sources.list.

I apologize for the long question, but believe once I can get a gui installed, i will be able to navigate this vm much easier.

Thanks!
Jay

Comment: I've never heard of Owncloud, but just from looking through the directories, the repo seems to have moved to https://attic.owncloud.com/org/download/repositories/8.2/Ubuntu_14.04/. I'm guessing the "attic" part means it's deprecated.

Comment: Building on what @wjandrea said, it looks like if you find the owncloud line in your /etc/apt/sources.list (or perhaps in a file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d) if you just replace the line with the one in his comment, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means, that some line on source.list if reffering to a web resource which doesn't exist and the simplest solution would be by replacing the sources.list file with the Ubuntu's default and updated sources.list.

Here's a pastebin link to Generic Sources.list :  http://pastebin.com/raw/uzhrtg5M

Or generate sources.list according to your preference by this online tool :  https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Btw did you try finding the specific line that is causing errors?